# How to detect Night Mode event - CSS / JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there any CSS prefix for night mode or javascript event that trigger when user change the mode? I want custom colors for the element if the user enables night mode from the [**browser setting**](https://blogs.opera.com/mobile/2015/05/opera-mini-night-mode-reduces-eye-strain-night-browsing/).

Thanks

Comment: No its not work if user enable night mode from browser setting

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It’s almost 2020 and we have now css media query to detect night mode.

```
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark){
  body {
    background-color: black;
    color: #ccc;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a CSS filter, I'm not sure that Twitter used something like this (no images were inverted only text and background.

note1: you can lower index of invert filter, for ex: .8
note2: no IE support :( but Edge support it

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
  $('.wrap').toggleClass('day night') ;
});
```

```css
.wrap{
  background: white;
}
.day{
  filter: invert(0);
}

.night{
  filter: invert(1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="wrap day">
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/200/150/any" />

  <p>Lorem ipsus </p>
  <button>Day / night</button>
  
 </div>
```

Comment: Actually my main question is how to detect either  user enable night mode or not

Comment: on twitter specifically you think?

Comment: there is an option on mobile browser especially "enable Night Mode" i want to track that option is there any event for that ?

Comment: I don't think so there is

Answer (score 0):

Actually, today we can not only use `@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark)` in CSS like you've mentioned, but also check with js

```
const isDarkMode = window.matchMedia && 
    window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches
```

and listen to changes in it:

```
window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)')
      .addEventListener('change', event => {
  if (event.matches) {
    //dark mode
  } else {
    //light mode
  }
})
```

(gratefully copy-pasted from [this article](https://codingshala.com/javascript/how-to-detect-dark-mode-using-javascript/), which may be not the original as the code is repeated in several others)

I'm not sure how to determine whether current browser will detect anything with these. I presume one should check if `window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)')` is an object, but this is only my hypothesis, I haven't found any definitive info about this.

Answer (score -1):

Because "night mode" will involve not only changing the background color, but also font colors (plus potentially a lot of other things) I would recommended a solution such as this:

**Example HTML:**

```
<body class="night">
```

Now, in standard mode the `body` tag wouldn't have the `night` class by default, but you would add this via a toggle class function such as jQuery's [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/).

Then in the CSS do something like...

**CSS:**

```
body {
    color: #000;
    background-color: #fff;
}

body.night {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #000;    
}
```

*NB: Example only, please don't use white text on a black background :)*

Now when the class is toggled and the `night` class is added, all the colors will change and the page will be in "night" mode.

Unsure if you also want instructions on making this mode "stick" during page refresh/navigation; if so, that is probably best handled with a `session` or a `cookie` that expires on browser close.

Comment: But how to detect user change the mode ?

Comment: There is no detection, only a function. Either a **button** or **toggler** that will initialize `darkmode.css` (for example). I did it by creating a `jQuery` function that appends `<link type="stylesheet" href="darkmode.css>"` to the `<head>` tag when user wants to enable the `Dark Mode`. But that's **not** very efficient, since the browser doesn't saves the user preference (no cache enabled).

Comment: @IsmailFarooq What do you mean "detect" - do you mean what I was talking about in my last sentence? Making sure night mode stays on during navigation around the site after the user has toggled it on?

Comment: @Brett there is an option in browser setting especially in mobile browser (read this article > https://blogs.opera.com/mobile/2015/05/opera-mini-night-mode-reduces-eye-strain-night-browsing/ ) i want to check if user enable this mode i want add class on body

Comment: Oh, no sorry, I'm not sure about how to check that setting I'm afraid. You should probably specify that in your question though to get better answers. :)